# Recommended setup with azure app and retail website

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an app running on azure, built by a professional.
I now want to create a retail "frontend" for the app - who we are, what we do etc.

I'm looking for advice for the best setup for my needs.

Current setup: domain.com points to azure app = ok
I want domain.com to point to retail website with a sign-in button to go to app.

My options (as I know it)

1. Create HTML/CSS files and then try to load them into Azure as the landing pages and all sit on domain.com
2. Create website on a separate server using a CMS. Point domain.com to CMS server and then create a new subdomain e.g. app.domain.com for the azure app. When anyone goes to domain.com - they get retail site - when they click "sign-in" they get directed to app.domain.com

I am leaning towards option 2 because I have the skills in-house to achieve this quickly and cheaply and also, putting it into a CMS makes it easy to update and manage moving forwards.  Option 1 will require assistance from .Net/azure expert, which isn't too bad but would ideally prefer to avoid.

Is Option 1 far superior that I should forego the CMS setup and easy future management? OR does it not really matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, I suggest you choose option2.

As you says, option2 is cheap and easily achieved since you have the skills in-house to finish it.

As far as I know, the service plan could create multiple web service, so you could also publish the CMS to the azure.

Besides, azure also provide the CMS to easily create the good web application. Like [wordpress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-create-web-app-from-marketplace), [Umbraco](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2013/04/08/build-your-own-web-site-using-azure-for-free-in-5-minutes/) and so on.

Finally, one day if you find CMS couldn't access your requirement, you could also find the coder to create the page and publish to your site again.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not overly experienced in provisioning. If I followed this guide: https://wplift.com/wordpress-microsoft-azure could i do it all in the same account/instance and not damage the app at all?

Comment: As far as I know, you could create a Virtual applications and directories in your web app service to run multiple appltion in one web app service. More details, you could refer to this artilce: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/

Comment: Thanks. I come from a linux CPanel world so the whole Azure, app service world is a bit sketchy to me but I will see how I go.